# Is there a way to stop my website pushing notification "allow/block" requests to chrome users?

Tags: javascript, html, laravel

My website currently sends push notifications to users when accessing the site for the first time, is there a way to remove this push notification request?

TIA

Comment: yes, don't send push notifications to users

Comment: I'm not sure what you are asking. I'm assuming you are not asking whether it's possible to send push notifications to users without them allowing you to send push notifications?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Use this in your .js file

```
Notification.requestPermission();
```

Create a button for "Enable Notification" in .html file

```
<button id="enable">Enable notifications</button>
```

When pressing this button app requests notification for the app (.js file)

```
    function askNotificationPermission() {
  // Asking for permissions
  function handlePermission(permission) {
    // button set for shown or hidden, depending on the user's selection
    if(Notification.permission === 'denied' || Notification.permission === 'default') {
      notificationBtn.style.display = 'block';
    } else {
      notificationBtn.style.display = 'none';
    }
  }

  // Check if the browser actually supports notifications
  if (!('Notification' in window)) {
    console.log("This browser does not support notifications.");
  } else {
    if(checkNotificationPromise()) {
      Notification.requestPermission()
      .then((permission) => {
        handlePermission(permission);
      })
    } else {
      Notification.requestPermission(function(permission) {
        handlePermission(permission);
      });
    }
  }
}
```